# Small population $t$-test

Tags: statistics

If the population is small, can I use the normal distribution or I need to use $t$-student like if it was a sample?

eg: In a class of $8$ students, $4$ male and $4$ female, I need to compare the height mean. I know the variance and the mean.

This is not a sample, because I'm getting all the population. Right? But the population is too small. So I'm confused which way to take.

Comment: If you have data on the entire population, there is no need to perform such a test on the data. Statistics is meant to perform inference on a population given a sample of data from the population.

Comment: You mean I just compare the averages?

Comment: So probably I should consider that the class of 8 students is a sample.

Comment: In which case, if the class is a sample, your first questions to yourself would include: what's the population of interest? Do I have a random sample from that population? (If I don't, should I be using something that assumes that I do?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you consider the class of 8 students to be a *population* or a *sample* depends on the question you are interested in asking:

1. "Is there a difference in the mean height among males versus females **in that class only**?"
2. "Is there evidence to suggest that there is a difference in mean height among males versus females **for all such classes in general**?"

In other words, if you were interested only in that specific class of 8 students, then there is no statistical inference or estimation involved.  You simply calculate the mean for each group and compare them.  But if you were interested in using the measurements taken from that class of students as being representative of a broader, unobserved population of students in similar classes, then there is sampling variation, and statistical inference is involved.  Such an inference relies on a number of assumptions; for example, that the class from which you observed the data is "reasonably representative" of the population on which you want to make such an inference.

In such a case, the small sample size may result in low statistical power, but in itself does not invalidate the basis for a statistical test.  Plainly speaking, it is often desirable but not necessary to have large sample sizes in order to do a statistical test.  If you were to use a two-sample $t$ test, there are two more assumptions being made:  that the heights of each student is independent and normally distributed, and that the variance in height among males and females are equal (but unknown).

Comment: Much clear now, thank you.